# Hadoop (HDFS) - взаимодействие с данными через Java

Tags: java, hadoop

Я пытаюсь взаимодействовать с файлами HDFS (читать, создавать и т.д.) с помощью следующего кода:

```
static String hdfs = "hdfs://URL:PORT";
static String pathToFile = "/folder/subfolder/filename.txt";

Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfs);

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfs), conf);

if (fs instanceof DistributedFileSystem) {
    LOGGER.info("HDFS is the underlying filesystem");
} else {
    LOGGER.info("Other type of file system " + fs.getClass());
}
FSDataInputStream in = null;
try {
    in = fs.open(new Path(pathToFile));
    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, System.out, 4096, false);
    LOGGER.info("End Of file: HDFS file read complete");
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeStream(in);
}
```

Но постоянно получаю одну и ту же ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: 
java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: 
"URL/IP"; destination host is: "URL":PORT;
```

Тем не менее, файловая система валидная, о чём сигнализирует строка логера:

```
2017-12-27 18:17:10 INFO Main:31 - HDFS is the underlying filesystem
```

Искал на форумах, в гугле, но в итоге получаю всё ту же ошибку. Возможно есть идеи, как решить её?

P.S.: пробовал запускать .jar файл на кластере, но заканчивается так же безрезультатно, разве что локальный адрес в ошибке другой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Загрузите конфигурацию из актуальных файлов `core-site.xml` и `hdfs-site.xml`. Сделать это можно следующим образом (только подставить соответствующие пути):

```
conf.addResource(new Path("file:///etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml"));
conf.addResource(new Path("file:///etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));
```

Эти файлы обычно лежат в папке `{$HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop`, поэтому стоит прочитать системную переменную, сформировать пути и загрузить конфигурацию. Иногда, например, если Hadoop ставился через менеджер пакетов, файлы конфигурации могут лежать в другом месте. В таком случае нужный путь можно прочитать из переменной `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`.